# Jquery: submit function not working at sending form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit, form-submit

i have a form, which I need to validate with jquery, to see if some fields are empty or not, but when i submit it with this function:

```
$("#servicio-tecnico-1").submit(function( event ) {
        return validar_form();
});
```

When i submit the function it does nothing and send the form also with empty fields. ¿How can i make it work?

Just in case i made a JSFiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/ricardojriosr/hr97240j/1/

Thanks in advance

Comment: some of the variables are out of scope, and the radio button has also a problem, other than it'll work ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have 2 variables `i` and `j` which are declared in a inner function which is throwing error when used outside the inner function

```
$("#servicio-tecnico-1").submit(function (event) {
    var valid = validar_form();
    return valid;
});
```

then

```
var i = 0;
$('.vfb-radio').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        i = i + 1;
    }
});
var j = 0;
$('.vfb-checkbox').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        j = j + 1;
    }
});
```

In the above snippet, `i/j` were inside the `each` loop and it was used outside the loop

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fykvn1wy/)

---

But those 2 set of codes can be simplified to

```
var i = $('.vfb-radio:checked').length;
var j = $('.vfb-checkbox:checked').length;
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fykvn1wy/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery validate to perform validation and then submit. More info @ http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

```
$(".selector").validate({
submitHandler: function(form) {
// do other things for a valid form
form.submit();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#servicio-tecnico-1").submit(function( event ) {

if ( validar_form() === true ) {
    //form is valid now submit it
    return;
  }
else {
      // prevent form submittal maybe return an error
      event.preventDefault();
}
});
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plugin like [jqueryvalidation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)
It is well documented. And a demo [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/radio-checkbox-select-demo.html), including radio buttons.